Unity Android : Google Play complains about App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher
I've published my Unity made Android app on google play. And it complains that my app is not targeting the the API Level 34.
However, I've specifically targeted this Api in the Player Settings.
And reverse engineering the manifest prooves it :

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:compileSdkVersion="34" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="14"
android:installLocation="preferExternal" package=

Also, it complains that
> <uses-permission
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

is missing but it's in the manifest as well. (I've enable custom manifest and pasted it).
Other than that the app is downloadable once published and seems to work fine. But it says that the deadline to switch to API 34 is August, so why is it not detecting that the app targets the right API ?
Thanks
